# Creating variable array object with for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop

I have a `for` loop that pulls data from a MySQL server. I would like the four values to be put into variables so I can use them later. Here's the code I have; for some reason, it says `thev` is undefined?

```
create();

function create(){

for(var i=0;i<4;i++){

        var thev=[];

        client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind=?',[i], function(err,result){
        thev[i] = result[0].curattend;

        });

        }
        return thev;
}
  console.log(thev[2]);
```

I would appreciate any advice on this problem.

Comment: @minitech That "may" was in regard to "[likely]" (as it's technically possible .. but oh, bother). I should have used stricter language, though - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems here.

1. `thev` is local to `create`. You don’t assign the return value of `create` to anything, so it’s still not going to be defined.
2. `var thev = [];` should not be inside the `for` loop. It’ll only end up containing one element. Or it would, but…
3. The callback to `query` is not just there for fun; it’s an asynchronous call, and is 100% sure to not have happened by the time you actually return from the function.

I would just do it using the [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) library:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var result = [];

    while(start < end) {
        result.push(start);
        start++;
    }

    return result;
}

async.map(range(0, 4), function(i, callback) {
    client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind = ?', [i], function(err, result) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, result[0].curattend);
    });
}, function(err, thev) {
    // Continue
});
```

Comment: I didnt notice the async inside loop.